# NBehave story output in resharper

Tags: resharper, nbehave

I wrote a bunch of stories using NBehave.

Now I have seen examples where the output is display in human readily format <s>([see this example](http://www.codeplex.com/NBehave/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home))</s>[Wayback machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20081212231239/http://www.codeplex.com/NBehave/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home)

Is there any way to get this output in resharper?

Comment: Notice that the link is dead. The project is now on github: https://github.com/nbehave/NBehave/wiki/Getting%20Started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://enceradeira.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-get-console-output-working-with.html) was posted by Jörg Jenni on his blog. He shows how to get nBehave output to display:

> When working with the latest build of NBehave 0.4 you may notice that
>   there is no output written to the ReSharper Testrunner Output anymore.
>
> Here is how I did workaround the problem. I derived the specs from the
>   following class and every thing was fine again:
>
> ```
> public class SpecBaseWithConsoleOutput: SpecBase
> {
>   private EventHandler<EventArgs<MessageEventData>> addedHandler;
>   private EventHandler<EventArgs<Scenario>> scenarioCreatedHandler;   
>   private EventHandler<EventArgs<Story>> storyCreatedHandler;
>   public override void MainSetup()
>   {
>     base.MainSetup();
>     addedHandler = (o, a) => Console.WriteLine(a.EventData.Message);
>     scenarioCreatedHandler = (o, a) => Console.WriteLine(a.EventData.Title);
>     storyCreatedHandler = (o, a) => Console.WriteLine(a.EventData.Title);
>     Story.MessageAdded += addedHandler;
>     Story.ScenarioCreated += scenarioCreatedHandler;
>     Story.StoryCreated += storyCreatedHandler;
>   }
>   public override void MainTeardown()
>   {
>     Story.MessageAdded -= addedHandler;
>     Story.ScenarioCreated -= scenarioCreatedHandler;
>     Story.StoryCreated -= storyCreatedHandler;
>     base.MainTeardown();
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: What about new release where Story is obsolete?